# Copying large tables from one redshift db to another using pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

So im trying to copy a moderately sized schema from one database. (Copy as in i need to replicate this schema on another database in the same cluster or server)

The small ones copied fine.
But while moving one of the large ones (95536 records). I got an `XX000 Disk Full` error.

So i ran a `VACUUM()` and the copy proceeded past the point of failure but failed again with the same error at a later time.

Method im using

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# Create
# source_db_engine
# destination_db_engine
with source_db_engine.begin() as src_conn:
    table = pandas.read_sql_table("table", "schema", con=src_conn)
    table.to_csv("table.csv")

with destination_db_engine.begin() as dest_conn:
    src_table = pandas.read_csv("table.csv")
    src_table.to_sql_table("table", "schema",
                           index=False, if_exists='append',
                           con=dest_conn)
```

1. Is there a way to do it such that each record can be inserted with its own transaction?
2. What could be the possible reason for the `Disk Full` since the source and destination dbs are completely identical?

Comment: Did you consider using [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) and [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) instead? Or using UNLOAD and then reading it in as an external table?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, but i was trying to do it without using S3. Thought this method would be faster

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Is the error coming from Amazon Redshift, or is it coming from Python/Pandas? If the latter, then it is probably because your code is reading data from Redshift into (presumably) memory. When the memory gets too full, it will 'page' the virtual memory to disk. If there is insufficient disk space to store the virtual memory pages, then it will generate a Disk Full. Therefore, increase the amount of disk space available to the application (on the computer where the code is running, not the database).

Comment: Your method would _not_ be faster since it is 'processing' each record through Pandas. Using UNLOAD and COPY would be the fastest method, since it would utilize the parallel processing capabilities of Redshift.